# iOS today widget for two trargets in same project

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8-today-widget, ios-extensions

I have a today widget, (that I've successfully localised for specific target), but it only shows for one build target I have, the main version of the app.
How can I set it to be available to other (/all) target in the same project?

Comment: Each target is an app (in your case, I guess). The relationship between app and extension is a one-to-on relationship. So you need an extension for each target/app. To reuse code, use dynamic frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your today target needs to start with the same bundle id as the containing target.

assuming your apps are com.Mackstein.target1 and com.Mackstein.target2

then you will need two today widgets with bundle ids something like:

com.Mackstein.target1.today1 and com.Mackstein.target2.today2

the easiest way to achieve this is just to duplicate the existing today1 widget target, tweak the bundle id, and then include the new today2 target in the target2

it is annoying, but I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: Same as what I've seen. Fortunately it's possible to use the same code in both extension targets, when that makes sense.

Comment: @TomHarrington how can I use the code and UI of the original widget without duplicating everything?